# Yii2 query with all() returns less data than expected

Tags: php, yii2

I want to find all data from database with this query:

```
 $dataSearch = House::find()
   ->select(["number","DATE(reg_date) AS date","((value) > 100) AS result","info"])
   ->join("INNER JOIN", Owner::tableName(), Owner::tableName().'.number_ow= '.House::tableName().'.number_ow')
   ->andWhere([House::tableName().'.number_ow'=>$house->number_ow])
   ->andFilterWhere([House::tableName().'.space'=>$space])
   ->orderBy([House::tableName().'.reg_date'=>SORT_DESC,'info'=>SORT_ASC]);


    $data = $dataSearch->asArray()->all();
```

If I perform the query with `all()` return only a few part of the results, but if I perform the raw SQL query on the database, I get all the results. I don't understand where the problem is.

This is raw SQL:

```
SELECT `number`, DATE(reg_date) AS date, ((value) > 100) AS result, `info` 
FROM `ho_house` INNER JOIN `ho_owner` ON ho_owner.number_ow = oh_ho_house.number_ow 
WHERE (`ho_house`.`number_ow`=2100174106) AND (`ho_house`.`space`='m')
ORDER BY `ho_house`.`reg_date` DESC, `info`
```

Comment: Please pasted your raw Query and also the Query generated by YII. This should be  given by $dataSearch->createCommand()->getRawSql()

Comment: Edit with raw query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because `ActiveQuery` tries to remove duplicated models from results of query with JOIN (for example if house have 2 owners, house data will be repeated twice in results set). In your case, if you want to raw data from database, you should use `Query`:

```
$dataSearch = (new Query())
   ->select(["number","DATE(reg_date) AS date","((value) > 100) AS result","info"])
   ->from(House::tableName())
   ->join("INNER JOIN", Owner::tableName(), Owner::tableName().'.number_ow= '.House::tableName().'.number_ow')
   ->andWhere([House::tableName().'.number_ow'=>$house->number_ow])
   ->andFilterWhere([House::tableName().'.space'=>$space])
   ->orderBy([House::tableName().'.reg_date'=>SORT_DESC,'info'=>SORT_ASC]);


$data = $dataSearch->all();
```

But if you really need `ActiveQuery`, you should configure [`$indexBy`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-querytrait#$indexBy-detail) to return unique ID for every row.

Answer (score 0):

Replace andWhere with Where  Check this code

```
 $dataSearch = House::find()
   ->select(["number","DATE(reg_date) AS date","((value) > 100) AS result","info"])
   ->join("INNER JOIN", Owner::tableName(), Owner::tableName().'.number_ow= '.House::tableName().'.number_ow')
   ->where([House::tableName().'.number_ow'=>$house->number_ow])
   ->andFilterWhere([House::tableName().'.space'=>$space])
   ->orderBy([ClosedOperation::tableName().'.reg_date'=>SORT_DESC,'info'=>SORT_ASC]);


    $data = $dataSearch->asArray()->all();
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I tried it and it doesn't work

Comment: Using `where()` will reset any existing condition (which may be initially set in `find()` as default condition for all queries). Using `andWhere()` should be preferred, since it is more flexible (unless your really want to reset query criteria).